# Can't get Apache POI autosizeColumn() to work right

Tags: java, apache, excel, apache-poi

Ok so I know you have to add the autoSizeColumns() method after you enter all your data into the sheet and workbook. And that is what I am doing but it is only resizing to the width of the last Cell entered??

```
public void writeFile() {
            Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
            Sheet s = wb.createSheet();
            try {

                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                        this.getSelectedFile());
                // create a new workbook

                // create a new sheet

                // declare a row object reference
                Row r = null;
                // declare a cell object reference
                Cell c = null;
                // in case of plain ascii
                wb.setSheetName(0, "Street Light Report");
                // create a sheet with 30 rows (0-29)
                // int rownum;
                // short rownum;
                // PrintWriter printOut = new PrintWriter(
                // this.getSelectedFile());
                String[] colName = { "Light Id", "Flagged",
                        "Malfunction", "Comments", "Location", "Date" };
                // printOut.println("Light Id,Flagged,Malfunction,Comments,Location,Date");
                Connections.connect();
                String[][] data = Connections.searchForFlagged();
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    r = s.createRow(i);
                }
                r.setRowNum(0);
                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                    c = r.createCell(j);
                    switch (j) {
                    case 0:
                        c.setCellValue(colName[j]);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        c.setCellValue(colName[j]);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        c.setCellValue(colName[j]);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        c.setCellValue(colName[j]);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        c.setCellValue(colName[j]);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        c.setCellValue(colName[j]);
                        break;

                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                    r.setRowNum(i + 1);
                    for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {

                        c = r.createCell(j);

                        // System.out.println(data[i][j]);

                        switch (j) {
                        case 0:
                            c.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
                            c.setCellValue(Integer.parseInt(data[i][j]));
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            if (data[i][j].equals("true"))
                                c.setCellValue("Yes");
                            else
                                c.setCellValue("No");
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if (data[i][j].equals("I"))
                                c.setCellValue("Intermittent");
                            else
                                c.setCellValue("Not Functional");
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            c.setCellValue(data[i][j]);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            c.setCellValue(data[i][j]);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            c.setCellValue(data[i][j]);
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }
                                        wb.getSheetAt(0).setPrintGridlines(true);
                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                    s.autoSizeColumn(j);
                }
                wb.write(out);
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you do not have too many columns. Can you try defining each column like this:

```
sheet.autoColumnWidth(column number); //0 for the first column, 1 for the second, etc.
```

If that works then there is something wrong with your loop.